# jQuery html() convert html code in wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having really weird issue atm.

I have div

```
<div id="testId"  class="some-class">
</div>
```

From js position I'd like to insert into this div html code

```
$('#testId').html("<a href="somelink">SOME_ID</a>")
```

By calling that I'd like to have hyperlink in SOME_ID. Unfortunetly html() converts it in that way:

```
<a href="somelink"></a>SOME_ID
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you have a question, it might help to use the error console (in chrome, that's ctrl+shift+j or F12) and look for errors. Many times, it will help you solve your own problem or at least help you do a google search for your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are handling the quotes in incorrect way. You should check consoles for errors. either use:

```
$('#testId').html("<a href='somelink'>SOME_ID</a>");
```

or

```
$('#testId').html('<a href="somelink">SOME_ID</a>');
```

**For adding dynamic href from variable:**

```
var smhref="http://jsfiddle.net/z25xd57c/";
$('#testId').html('<a href="'+smhref+'">SOME_ID</a>');
```

Comment: thanks alot, thats newbie mistake. I had trouble with pure link without any viarables.

Comment: @ojciecmatki: glad it helps. always check the console for error.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `+` operator to join strings and variables in Javascript.

```
var somelink = "http://www.google.com",
    some_ID  = "Google";

$('#testId').html("<a href=" + somelink + ">" + SOME_ID + "</a>")
```

Will return `<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/y4kqm1af/1/

HTML

```
<div id="testId" class="some-class"></div>
```

Script

```
var somelink="https://www.google.com";
var  SOME_ID="Google";
$('#testId').append("<a href=" + somelink + ">" + SOME_ID + "</a>")
```